# How to generate a key from a SHA256 hash using Bouncy Castle?

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

I want to take a SHA256 hash and generate a key from it using Bouncy Castle (Spongy Castle actually). In the code excerpt that follows, retval is the value returned by the SHA256Digest (a byte array) and finalKey should be the key that was generated from the SHA256 hash.

```
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH", "SC");
X509EncodedKeySpec ks = new X509EncodedKeySpec(retval);
ECPublicKey finalKey = (ECPublicKey)kf.generatePublic(ks);
```

I get the message "encoded key spec not recognised" when I try to run the code, so I imagine that there is some specific format that retval should be in and that I can't just pass the byte array directly as outputted by the SHA256Digest like I am doing. The Bouncy Castle documentation doesn't seem helpful, or I am just not seeing the relevant section.

Comment: You can't create an EC key just from random bytes. You need some kind function that maps bytes to EC group elements.

Comment: You want to generate a random *public* key (point)? Why?

Comment: Looks like I goofed up. I want to create a key to use with a HMAC. It looks like SecretKeySpec is actually what I want to use.

Comment: Yup, that makes a hole lot of sense compared to generating a public key without a private key. Note that you may want to use an official KDF (key derivation function) such as HKDF instead of a hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I wanted to use SecretKeySpec. The following is an example.

```
SecretKeySpec finalKey = new SecretKeySpec(retval, "RAW");
```